# A possible structure for a Node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, node-modules

In my node project I'm using this basic template structure for a single module

```
(function() {

  var SimpleModule;
  SimpleModule = (function() {

    function SimpleModule(params) {

      /** private function */
      this.aPrivateFunction = function() {
        return "hidden";
      };

    }

    /** public function */
    SimpleModule.prototype.foo = function() {
      return "bar";
    }

    return SimpleModule;

  })();

  module.exports = SimpleModule;

}).call(this);
```

so that the caller module will do

```
var SimpleModule
 ,simpleModuleInstance;

SimpleModule = require('./simplemodule');
simpleModuleInstance = new SimpleModule();
simpleModuleInstance.foo();
```

Is this a approach formally correct in `Node`?

Comment: What's `MyModule`?

Comment: Formally - correctly, but why so complicated?

Comment: @Nonemoticoner typo fixed thanks.

Comment: @stdob-- the idea is to keep the `encapsulation` approach so hiding accessors and modules internals.

Comment: Unsure as to why you would wrap the module in another "immediately invoked function" when each file is already?

Comment: I guess there's no need of two nested iife

Comment: If the module is huge, and you need to use another files, you should use a folder to define your module, creating a package json with a main module, so that you encapsulate everything you need for that module in a folder, and exports just the main module. Then the require is done by folder name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a simpler approach? Modules are private by default, so everything's already encapsulated except what you export.

```
function SimpleModule(params) {
  /* Not really private!! */
  this.aPrivateFunction = function() {
    return "hidden";
  };
}

/** public function */
SimpleModule.prototype.foo = function() {
  return "bar";
}

module.exports = SimpleModule;
```

Comment: @NestorBritez Not really. If you're going to write `var instance = new SimpleModule()`, you're going to end up with `aPrivateFunction` on the instance. To get `aPrivateFunction` as a static method, you'd have to attach it directly to the constructor function: `SimpleModule.aPrivateFunction = function() ...`